# $lookup giving no results in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Note: Edits below where I tried this directly using mongo shell and correct collection names, but still the same issue.**

I am currently trying to learn Node and Mongodb. I am looking to understand how to add one document with another in a query. All the documentation points back to `$lookup`.

I have the two following models set up, which both work perfectly on their own

```
var BearSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', BearSchema);

var CommentSchema   = new Schema({
    creator_id : { type: String, ref: 'Bear' },
    comment: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

I will omit other set up details and get straight to the queries.

When I run `Bear.find()` I get the expected result...

```
    [
      {
        "_id": "585887a29b7915f437742b88",
        "name": "new bear",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
```

When I run `Comment.find()` I get the expected result...

```
[
  {
    "_id": "585887ae9b7915f437742b89",
    "creator_id": "584de876238179030d7d7916",
    "comment": "yoyoyo",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "585887e09b7915f437742b8a",
    "creator_id": "585887a29b7915f437742b88",
    "comment": "ok lets give this a go",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Note the `creator_id` in the second comment is the same as the `_id` in the bear result.

I then run

```
    Bear.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "Comment",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "creator_id",
                as: "comments"
            }
        }
    ], function (err, bears) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(bears);
    });
```

and get the following:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "585887a29b7915f437742b88",
    "name": "new bear",
    "__v": 0,
    "comments": []
  }
]
```

I was hoping the following would appear:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "585887a29b7915f437742b88",
    "name": "new bear",
    "__v": 0,
    "comments": [      
       {
         "_id": "585887e09b7915f437742b8a",
         "creator_id": "585887a29b7915f437742b88",
         "comment": "ok lets give this a go",
         "__v": 0
       }
     ]
  }
]
```

I cant understand in this situation how it would know what `"Comment"` is referring to.

EDIT: From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) I can see the `from` field says: `Specifies the collection in the same database to perform the join with. The from collection cannot be sharded.`

EDIT 2: In mongoshell I have ran the following queries and their results, as you can see the same issue is still appearing even with the correct collection name, however I can now see `ObjectId()` may be the issue...

```
> show collections
bears
comments


> db.bears.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("585887a29b7915f437742b88"), "name" : "new bear", "__v" : 0 }

> db.comments.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("585887ae9b7915f437742b89"), "creator_id" : "584de87623817903
0d7d7916", "comment" : "yoyoyo", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("585887e09b7915f437742b8a"), "creator_id" : "585887a29b7915f4
37742b88", "comment" : "ok lets give this a go", "__v" : 0 }


> db.bears.aggregate([ { $lookup: { from: "comments", localField: "_id", foreign
Field: "creator_id", as: "comments" } } ]);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("585887a29b7915f437742b88"), "name" : "new bear", "__v" : 0,
"comments" : [ ] }
```

Comment: Is that a typo in the foreign field "creator__id" in for "creator_id" ? And also local field should be _id.

Comment: sorry yes, but only from here as I swapping them around to see if that was the issue. Will fix it now

Comment: I ran the same query in mongo shell . worked fine for me. `db.Bear.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "Comment",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "creator_id",
                as: "comments"
            }
        }
])`

Comment: oh yea? I am testing using postman. I will try that thanks

Comment: when you say it worked fine, what do you mean? My issue isnt that Im getting an error, it just seems to be failing to find the comments

Comment: I mean I can find the comments when I run the query. may be you have different collection names. Do you have the plural names by any chance ?

Comment: What happens when you try `Comments` in the from field ?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I think this might be my issue, I dont know what is meant exactly by "collection name". I have the model created above as per the code. But I am not referring to it anywhere else, I am not using plurals anywhere. "Comments" doesnt work either as expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131100/discussion-between-sagar-reddy-and-adrian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this. There were two issues.

1. The Bear Schema _`id` is actually an `ObjectID()` so it wasnt comparing the two correctly.
2. I misunderstood what collection names were and so `Comment` would not have been recognised.

Solution:

When creating the `Comment` Model I used `Schema.ObjectId`

```
var CommentSchema   = new Schema({
    creator_id : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Bear' },
    comment: String
});
```

When doing the query I used `comments` instead of `Comment` as this was the collection named Mongoose created.

```
    Bear.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "comments",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "creator_id",
                as: "comments"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

whenever you'r using $lookup, you must add an extra "s" in "from" field.
for example:
if your table name is
"register" 
then you have to write
"registers"

Note: at the time of $lookup only